GCC resolves symbolic links to absolute paths, causing issues in Bazel builds
I am using GCC with Bazel. When I try to compile a source file using the GCC compiler, it resolves symbolic links to absolute paths, which creates problems in the Bazel build.
In my MODULE.bazel file, I am using new_local_repository to make my local folder an external dependency as shown below:
new_local_repository = use_repo_rule("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:local.bzl", "new_local_repository")

new_local_repository(
    name = "test_package", 
    path = "SIP_test", 
    build_file = "Bazel/BUILD.bazel"
)

The above code creates a symlink of the actual local folder in the external workspace.
Below is an example target in my BUILD.bazel file:
cc_library(
    name = "test",
    srcs = [
        "source/HelloWorld.c",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "@test_sip//:components/xxxx/test1.h",
        "@test_sip//:components/xxxx/test2.h",
    ],
    copts = DEFAULT_COPTS,
)

I have verified that there are no absolute paths defined anywhere in my configuration. However, I am encountering the following error during the Bazel build:
ERROR: D:/test/BUILD.bazel:8:15: Compiling source/HelloWorld.c failed: absolute path inclusion(s) found in rule '//:test':
the source file 'source/HelloWorld.c' includes the following non-builtin files with absolute paths (if these are builtin files, make sure these paths are in your toolchain):
  'D:/test/test_sip/components/xxxx/test1.h'
  'D:/test/test_sip/components/xxxx/test2.h'

